# using json data in javascript causing troubles

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json encoded result as

```
{  
    "result":[  
        {  
            "CODE":"STC\/R\/935",
            "WAY":"In",
            "DATE":"2016-02-19",
            "TYPE":"Re-Entry",
            "TKTP":"NA",
            "TIME":"2016-02-23 17:52:37"
        },
        {  
            "CODE":"5\/105",
            "WAY":"In",
            "DATE":"2016-01-30",
            "TYPE":"Re-Entry",
            "TKTP":"NA",
            "TIME":"2016-02-23 17:52:37"
        },
        {  
            "CODE":"356",
            "WAY":"In",
            "DATE":"2016-02-06",
            "TYPE":"Re-Entry",
            "TKTP":"NA",
            "TIME":"2016-02-23 17:52:37"
        },
        {  
            "CODE":"FCC\/ETC\/01",
            "WAY":"In",
            "DATE":"2016-02-10",
            "TYPE":"Re-Entry",
            "TKTP":"NA",
            "TIME":"2016-02-23 17:52:37"
        },
        {  
            "CODE":"3\/739",
            "WAY":"In",
            "DATE":"2016-02-03",
            "TYPE":"Re-Entry",
            "TKTP":"NA",
            "TIME":"2016-02-23 17:52:37"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i tried to iterate through it in javascript it is not excecuted. 
Hope somebody help. I already spent one full day googling about it.

```
function bringdata(){
    $.ajax({
        url:'report_entry.php',
        type:"POST",
        data:{nameV:$('#fq').val()},
        async: false,
        success: function(data){                
            $.each(data, function(i,post){
                $("#magix").append("<li>+post.CODE+</li>");
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: json is invalid https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ ...also it should be "<li>" + post.CODE + "</li>

Comment: @LoganMurphy i did validation with that site. but all elements are got same like.Still could you pls recomend way to get it in standard from jsonencode ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix these lines

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
$.each(data.result, function(i,post){
    $("#magix").append("<li>"+post.CODE+"</li>");
});
```

Or without using jquery `$.each`,

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
data.result.forEach(function(post){
    $("#magix").append("<li>"+post.CODE+"</li>");
});
```

Comment: it is not fixed. Im sorry

Comment: @Bineesh Did you try ,parsing data first. `post =  JSON.parse(post)`

Comment: thanks for that words. it works. googled and thought. but still have some concerns. will see.

Comment: great.. happy to hear that

Answer (score 1):

You aren't concatenating your strings correctly.

```
$("#magix").append("<li>" + post.CODE + "</li>");
```

If you don't close off the quote marks correctly, you'll just make a string with `+`s in it.

Also, if your data matches the posted JSON, then you need to access the `result` property of `data` to get your array.

```
$.each(data.result, function(i, post) {
  $("#magix").append("<li>" + post.CODE + "</li>");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

With help of @zohaib ijaz, i could correct it like :

```js
function bringdata() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'report_entry.php',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      nameV: $('#fq').val()
    },
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      var divition = $('#magix');
      var bine = "bineesh";
      var count = 0;
      obj = JSON.parse(data);
      $.each(obj.result, function(i, post) {
        //alert("success");
        divition.append('<li>Name:' + obj.result[count].CODE + '</li>');
        count = count + 1;

      });
    }

  });
}
```